# Optimize.minimize initial guess

Tags: python, optimization, minimize

I am trying to comprehend the idea of optimize.minimize. However, I got stuck with a small problem. I do not understand that why we need an initial guess (x0) while using the optimize.minimize? Can anyone help me out??

Thank you so much.

Comment: could you give us an idea of what you are trying to attempt? a small demo of your code would be fine too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numerical optimisation basically says: here's a function *f*.

Let's say we're trying to find a minimum. Let's add a bit to our starting variable. What is *f(x + a)*? Does it go down? And let's add a bit more? Is *f(x + a + b)* smaller than that? Eventually, after trying a ton of different inputs, going up and down, you'll have a good idea of how the function behaves and where it is minimised.

To do this, you need to start someplace so that you can add or subtract from the *x* part of *f(x)*.

Comment: So, we just let the program know whether it should go down or not. Thank you sir.